# Add OnEmpty Widget to ListView.builder() inside FutureBuilder using flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am using Flutter to develop small application with floor for the database.

I am getting the data from the database using Future then listing all items in UI using FutureBuild.

**This is my code**
Getting the data from database:

```
@Query('SELECT * FROM Doctor')
  Future<List<Doctor>> findAllDoctor();
```

Getting data to UI

```
Future<List<Doctor>> findAllDoctor() async {
    return await database.doctorDao.findAllDoctor();
  }
```

Setting data into FutureBuilder:

```
return FutureBuilder(
      future: findAllDoctor(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Doctor>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  title: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                          "${snapshot.data![index].firstName} ${snapshot
                              .data![index].lastName}"),
                      Text(
                        snapshot.data![index].phone,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                      "${snapshot.data![index].address} ${snapshot.data![index]
                          .nameOfTheClinic}"),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        } else {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
```

I want to add new widget that tells me *no data* if there is no data in the table.

Comment: `if (snapshot.hasData) { return snapshot.data.isEmpty? Text('no doctors found') : ListView.builder(....`

Comment: sure, your welcome